# PHPMailer - Certain SMTP messages don't send

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a script that sends emails to users, which are sometimes divided into multiple messages depending on size. Here's the code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($the_message); $i++){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->Host = "my.smtp.server";
    $mail->Port = $email_port;
    $mail->Username = "my@email.com";
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->FromName = "My Name";
    $mail->IsHTML($is_html);
    if($is_html === TRUE){
       $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email client, or change your export to a plain text format.";
    }
    foreach($to as $address){
       $mail->AddAddress($address);
    }
    $mail->Body = $the_message[$i];
    $mail->Subject = $the_sub;
    $mail->Send();
}
```

This used to work great. Now, it seems that certain messages will never send. It seems to be a data issue (or perhaps the way PHPMailer sends lines to the server?), but I can't pinpoint why certain message segments are always rejected by the server.

The error message I get from PHPMailer is this:

> SMTP Error: Data not accepted.

And from PHP itself:

> Notice:  fputs(): send of 31 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection
>   reset by peer in class.smtp.php on line 580

Here is a segment of HTML data that always fails to send:

http://pastebin.com/LGYkTTFA

Note that size isn't an issue, I can successfully send much larger HTML messages than this. However, when I send multiple segments, this one is never accepted by the server.

Comment: what's in `$the_message`?

Comment: $the_message is an array of strings, it can be HTML or plain text.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code as it is in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *class.smtp.php*, line 51, I changed the constant `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` from **998** to **500**. This allowed all of my email segments to pass through.

I'm still not sure if the issue lies with my SMTP server or PHPMailer, I'll have to test it elsewhere.

**EDIT:** Tested using Gmail's SMTP server, and keeping **998** worked fine. This leads me to assume that my SMTP relay server is rejecting data sometimes depending on the length.

**EDIT2:** Still experienced failures with the above fix. I changed my port number and added SSL, and it is magically working. Wonky server issues...

Comment: This looks a lot like your server was the culprit. You're wrapping long lines that should be already permitted by smtp. Strange... Any strange rules in your smtp?

Comment: Yeah, definitely server. No weird rules that I know of. Even after this change, I experienced a few failures. I changed the port number and added SSL for the heck of it, and so far everything is working. *shrug*

Comment: hey, it's time to ask a question regarding your smtp server ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here, I rewrote it for you in a somewhat saner way. You don't need to create everything from scratch every time around the loop, just change the body and send again.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$the_message = array('Hello', 'there', 'Justin');
$to = array('tom@example.com', 'dick@example.net', 'harry@example.org');
$the_sub = 'Crazy subject';
$email_port = 25;
$from = 'justin@example.com';
$is_html = true;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = $email_port;
$mail->Username = "my@email.com";
$mail->Password   = "mypassword";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->Subject = $the_sub;
$mail->IsHTML($is_html);
$mail->WordWrap = 200;

if($is_html){
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email client, '.
     'or change your export to a plain text format.";
}
foreach($to as $address){
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
}
for($i=0; $i<count($the_message); $i++){
    $mail->Body = $the_message[$i];
    $mail->setWordWrap();
    $mail->Send();
}
```

**Update**: added word wrapping to deal with content with very long lines.

Comment: I forgot to say - it's much easier to test mail sending code using a fake mail server. There are some linked from [PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/index.html).

Comment: +1 for not recreating objects in a loop, it's so underestimated, I don't know where to begin ;)

Comment: I appreciate your desire to clean up my code, but I don't think it's related. My code has been sending plenty of emails just fine. The issue is either data or an obscure bug in the way PHPMailer sends lines of data to the server. I'm working on finding some non-private test data that exhibits the problem so I can post it.

Comment: Make sure you're using latest PHPMailer - at least 5.2.8 - as it has low-level changes to SMTP.

Comment: Also make sure to try with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` for detailed SMTP debug output.

Comment: I've updated to 5.2.8, it behaves the same. Please take a look at my data to see if you notice anything amiss there.

Comment: That text contains very long lines (more than the 998 chars SMTP allows) - I altered code to apply word wrapping, give it a go now.

Comment: This shouldn't matter, as there is code to handle long lines in class.smtp.php on line 532. I tried it anyway, but it didn't have any effect.